# Class Variables

Tags: document-classes, geometry, optional-arguments

I am exploring the use of class options, I was under the impression that optional arguments presented at the point of class declaration, were subsequently presented to all packages used thereafter.

Can someone explain to me why the following doesn't produce the output I would expect, which is to pass the geometry arguments (left, right, top, bottom) through to the geometry package.

```
\documentclass[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why would it? `\documentclass` does not have [parameters](http://www.nada.kth.se/~carsten/latex/class.html) like that. Or does it? That would be a useful feature in some cases, but with multiple packages using intersecting parameter lists...

Comment: This only seem to effect those options (and probably others, too), but, for example, using `\documentclass[showframe]{article} \usepackage{geometry}` works just fine.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Altough it works it still doesn't seem like a good thing to do for me because it can be really ambiguous. Is there a use-case when it should be considered to use or this is just a syntactic sweetener?

Comment: I have a custom class, and I need to pass some options thought, it seems like this problem effects a number of packages, for instance, biblatex. This question here is a MWE, clearly it is a trivial case, but it demonstrates the issue that I am having. For the moment, I have been using `\PassOptionsToPackage{...}` prior to the class declaration, however, I would prefer to put the options in the class declaration itself.

Comment: I can't explain "why". I can only tell you how you can access the parameters. :(

`\documentclass[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{article}

\makeatletter
\let\options\@curroptions
\makeatother

\usepackage[\options]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}`

Comment: I took another look. This seems to be "caused" by the `geometry` package... There's a warning in the log: `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [left=0cm,right=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm].`

Comment: This may be specific to [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) since it sets package options using a different approach than using `\ProcessOptions`.

Comment: @Werner, is it the same with biblatex?

Comment: @ADP: I haven't checked, but there may be packages other than [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) handling their options in a different way that what one would consider the "default way". So, perhaps.

Comment: @Werner, OK Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

While [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is meant to adjust paper and text block layouts, it also does us a favour and *overwrites* things that may be defined at the document class level. For example,

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{lipsum}
```

works without error as the [`article` class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) has a defined way of handling the `landscape` option:

```
\DeclareOption{landscape}
   {\setlength\@tempdima   {\paperheight}%
    \setlength\paperheight {\paperwidth}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {\@tempdima}}
```

However, `geometry`'s use of this is far superior, making

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{lipsum}
```

work just as expected, where `geometry` actually re-applied its own document layouts based on the `landscape` document class option.

This is what makes `geometry` special: it re-checks all the document class-level options (not just unused ones) to see whether it should override them or not. However, it does so in a very crude way. In fact, *key-only* options are properly evaluated (like `landscape`, or `showframe`), while *key-value* options are not (like `left=1cm` or `headheight=10pt`).

The only way to get around this is to supply the options verbatim to `geometry`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
%...
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0pt}
%...
```

or pass options using the traditional way via `\PassOptionsToPackage[<options>]{<package>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{margin=0pt}{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
%...
```